# Extract string after first comma and store it in another column using R

Tags: r

I want to split text after the first comma and put it in another column of same dataframe.

```
s2 <- data.frame(text =c("Hi Prashant, As per the contract, employees can avail for various services like gym, recreation center, etc","Various dishes are available in canteen like pasta, rice dishes, etc"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s2$new = gsub(".*,", "", s2)
```

But its splitting after last comma, which I don't want.

Expected output after splitting text after first comma and storing it another column called 'new' should look like:

first row: As per the contract, employees can avail for various services like gym, recreation center, etc.

second row: rice dishes, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sub`, and make the dot lazy:

```
s2$new <- sub("^.*?,", "", s2$text)
```

Or, another way:

```
s2$new <- sub("^[^,]*,", "", s2$text)
```

The problem with your current pattern is that `.*` by default is *greedy*, meaning it will consume everything up until the *last* comma.  But in your case, you want it to stop matching at the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using the `stringr` library and the `str_split_fixed` function which splits a vector of strings into a matrix of substrings at the pattern match.

```
library(stringr)

s2$new <- str_split_fixed(s2$text, ",", 2)[,2]
```